# Textbox entry with tab

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I want to know if there is any event for entering a TextBox after pressing tab key.

**For example**: I have a TextBox for `Name` and `LastName`, after I fill the TextBox for `Name` and press the Tab key to go to `LastName` TextBox I want to change the color or something for TextBox `LastName`.

Comment: Try the `Enter` event! Obviously there also is a `Leave` event.. It qill work not just when you use the tabe key, though.

Comment: Could you explain if you are making a WinForms or a WPF or some kind of Web application?

Comment: Im making a windowsForm

Comment: @TaW Thanks it works!

Answer (score 1):

This simple class could help a lot for your task

```
public class ControlColor
{
    private Color _setBColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0);
    private Color _setFColor = SystemColors.ControlText;

    public ControlColor(params Control[] ctls)
    {
        foreach (Control ctr in ctls)
        {
            ctr.Enter += new EventHandler(onEnter);
            ctr.Leave += new EventHandler(onLeave);
        }
    }
    public ControlColor(Color bkg, Color frg, params Control[] ctls)
    {
        _setFColor = frg;
        _setBColor = bkg;
        foreach (Control ctr in ctls)
        {
            ctr.Enter += new EventHandler(onEnter);
            ctr.Leave += new EventHandler(onLeave);
        }
    }

    private void onEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Control)
        {
            Control ctr = (Control)sender;
            ctr.BackColor = _setBColor;
            ctr.ForeColor = _setFColor;
        }

    }
    private void onLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control ctr = sender as Control;
        ctr.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
        ctr.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
    }
}
```

You could call it with code like this (LinqPAD test, but should be not a problem to adapt to Visual Studio)

```
void Main()
{
    Form f = new Form();
    TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
    t1.Location = new Point(0, 0);

    TextBox t2 = new TextBox();
    t2.Location = new Point(0, 20);

    ControlColor cl = new ControlColor(t1, t2);
    f.Controls.Add(t1);
    f.Controls.Add(t2);
    f.Show();

}
```

The class works receiving an array of controls from the caller. For each array the class register an event handler for the Leave and Enter events (these events are triggered when your controls get the focus) The final work is simply to paint the background (and eventually the foreground) with the colors choosen.